# Check if it is possible to transform one string to another using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve the below method by using recursion

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-possible-transform-one-string-another/

```
    static boolean abbreviation(String a, String b,int m, int n) {
    
    char[] x = a.toCharArray();
   
  
    if(m ==0|| n==0)
    return true;

    if(m==0 && n!=0)
    return false;

    if(n==0){
        for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++){
            
            //if any character is not in lower case, return false
            if( Character.isLowerCase( x[i] )){
                System.out.println(x[i]);
            return true;  
        
            }
        }
                
         return false;
    }
    if((a.charAt(m-1)==b.charAt(n-1))||
    (Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(m-1))==b.charAt(n-1))){
       return abbreviation(a,b,m-1,n-1);
    }else return abbreviation(a,b,m-1,n) &&  abbreviation(a,b,m,n-1);
    

  
}
```

I am getting`true` instead of `false` for below inputs

**Input 1**

AbCdE

AFE

**Input 2**

beFgH

EFG

Comment: can you also show the main function like your link show us?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 cases when traversing characters of two string

- Character matched (if lowercase then doing uppercase)
- Charcter not matched and first string character is lowercase
- Charcter not matched and first string character is uppercase

And base case if all character checked in first string then check all matched or not.

```
  boolean abbreviation(String a, String b, int m, int n) {
    if (m == 0)
      return n == 0;

    if (n > 0 && Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(m - 1)) == b.charAt(n - 1)) {
      return abbreviation(a, b, m - 1, n - 1);
    } else if(!Character.isUpperCase(a.charAt(m - 1))) {
      return abbreviation(a, b, m - 1, n);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Demo:

```
System.out.println(abbreviation("AbCdE", "AFE", 5, 3));
System.out.println(abbreviation("beFgH", "EFG", 5, 3));
System.out.println(abbreviation("beFgh", "EFG", 5, 3));
System.out.println(abbreviation("daBcd", "ABC", 5, 3));
```

Output:

```
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: gives IndexOut of bound for below input 
string1 :daBcd
String 2:ABC

Comment: Fixed now and added demo also

Comment: I tried submitting in hacker rank 6 test cases failed https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/abbr/problem